# Algorithm to fill slots

Tags: sql, algorithm, language-agnostic, math

I am searching for an algorithm to fill several slots, which are already filled to some level.

- The current levels and the available quantity to fill are known
- Resulting levels should be as equal as possible, but existing level cannot be reduced
- Slots are filled from left to right, so left slots get higher level if equal level is impossible

[Examples http://img695.imageshack.us/img695/6529/fill.png](http://img695.imageshack.us/img695/6529/fill.png)

The image above shows six examples, each column represents a slot. The grey area is already filled, the blue are is the expected position of the new elements.

---

I could iterate through my slots and increase the quantity on the lowest slot by `1` until the available quantity is consumed, but I wonder about how to actually **calculate** the new filling levels.

I am going to implement this with `SQL`/`PL/SQL`, other code is just as welcome though :)

Comment: Trying to understand the image/issue: are the blue nos available slots or  slots already taken? Also, is each bar a slot?

What do you mean by 'new filling levels'?

Comment: @Anon: The grey area is already taken, the blue area is the expected position of the new elements. By "new filling levels" I mean the new levels (heights) of the slots (=vertical lines). Hope this helps!

Comment: So, each column is a slot? Your image had spacing between columns which seems to suggest that groups of columns are slots.

Comment: @Anon: Yes, each column is a slot. I added a description of the image, hope it's more clear now.

Comment: First, "as equal as possible" should be formally defined.
Several alternative definitions are possible, such as: minimize the maximum difference between slots; minimize the maximum difference between slots that have changed; minimize the average difference, etc.

Comment: @Marco: Thanks! It's about minimizing the maximum difference between slots. Like filling the slots with water, filling starts with the lowest levels. Does that help?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the behaviour if you try to fill more than the available space?

Comment: @ANeves: In my case, the available space is not restricted. Slots are filled until the required quantity is stored.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty straightforward.

You can visualize this as pouring water and let it fill, except for certain cases *.

1. Sort.  You can also use a priority queue.
2. Keep track of the number of current min columns.
3. Get the min column with the second min column.
4. Fill the min column with either the number of available items, or up to the second min column.
5. Increment the count of current min columns.
6. Go to step 4 until all columns are at the same level, except use the number of available items, or delta (second min - first min ) times the number of current min columns.  If the number of available items is not enough, just do simple math (division and remainder) to fill the columns, and use the remainder to fill from the left.
7. When all the columns are on the same level, use the simple math part described in step 6.

You should be good.

This algorithm runs in `O( n log n )` time.

*Some cases this doesn't make sense, but you would still want to do it anyhow:

```
 #
 #
##
###
###
```

In that case, you would fill the third column, then the first, then the second, but of course it's not quite filling water.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a greedy algorithm with randomization to break ties will be sufficient.

Let n be the number of slots you need to fill.

Step 1: Loop through the columns to identify the columns that have the least no of filled up slots. Skip the columns that are already filled up.

Step 2: If no of columns are identified in step 1 is greater than one then choose one at random.

Step 3: Set n = n-1

Repeat steps 1, 2 and 3 till n = 0 or you do not have any empty columns.

Answer (score 0):

1. Sort the columns from lowest to highest starting levels.
2. Compute the cumulative starting use for the (sorted) columns.
3. Compute for each column how much new fill will be used by filling up to the height of that column.  The amount used would be the height of the column times the column index, minus the cumulative starting use of all columns before it.
4. Pick the column with index i that will use the most of your new fill without going over.  Fill all columns up to column i to the height of column i (which will use the amount of fill computed in step #3 for column i), then the remaining fill goes on the first i columns evenly `floor(remaining / i)` plus one additional fill on the first `remaining % i` columns.
5. Undo sort of columns to get result.

This should take time linear in the number of columns (independent of the amount of fill).

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like the classic [Knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)
There's a number of different language solutions for this using different algorithms at [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Knapsack_Problem) though I'm not sure there's anything in PL/SQL

Comment: I fail to see the connection to the Knapsack problem. I don't have any weights/values to choose from, I need to find out how many items go to which slot.

Comment: All your items are of the same weight and value: Look at specific subsets/variants of the knapsack problem such as the Bin Packing Problem (multiple knapsacks) and the Partition Problem... all of which are referenced on that Wikipedia page